# Form submission and receipt on the same page (Laravel, php, blade)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Help!!!
I need the entered value to be displayed in input after sending.

TestController.php

```
class TestController extends Controller {

public function form(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
        echo 'REQUEST GET';                      
        return view('test');  
    }
    
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $text = $request->input('text');
        echo 'REQUEST POST';
        echo '<br>';
        echo $text;  
        return view('test', ['text', $text]);
    }
}
```

test.blade.php

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 {{ $CONTAINER_SETTINGS->OFFSET_MD }} {{ $CONTAINER_SETTINGS->WIDTH_MD }}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="header" class="panel-heading">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-btn fa-users"></i>Test</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <form action="{{ url('test') }}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    @if(isset($text))
                    <input type="text" name="text" value="{{ $text }}">                                      
                    @else
                    <input type="text" name="text" >                                      
                    @endif
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

web.php (routes)

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@form');
Route::post('test', 'TestController@form');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUEEn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T0Sy.png)

Comment: The idea of a controller (specifically a [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)) is to separate this stuff. Read more about it on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't send data with indexed array when return view.

Check out Laravel Documentation for [**Passing Data To Views**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Try this:

```
return view('test', ['text' => $text]);
```

Comment: omg.. rly. Thank you! 
Strange, but here separated by commas. Maybe the version is different?
url: http://code.mu/ru/php/framework/laravel/book/prime/forms/2/

Comment: I don't think so. Laravel's old versions also use this way. In shared link, syntax is wrong. In next part correct usage is shown. http://code.mu/ru/php/framework/laravel/book/prime/3